# Does the noun "der Cent" have a plural form?

Tags: noun

I googled the word "der Cent" and some resources show that the plural form is "die Cents". I'm a little confused because my dictionary shows that the noun "der Cent" doesn't have the plural form. Could you please explain this case?

no plural:
PONS: [der Cent](https://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung/deutsch-englisch/Cent?bidir=1)

Plural: Cents

[image]

Wiki: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Cent

Comment: PONS: Cent <-[s], -[s]>, so the plural is Cents. However, when used like a unit, the singular is used: Das kostet 20 Cent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, it does have a plural form, but it is not used in the way that the plural is used in English.

In German, money counts don't take a plural when given as a unit. E.g., "Das kostet 10 Euro und 50 Cent."

Comment: When do you use the noun "Cents" ?

Comment: When talking about more than one 1ct coin.

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt Could you please give an example? My dictionary says 50 cent instead of 50 cents. 
https://de.pons.com/übersetzung/deutsch-englisch/Cent?bidir=1

Comment: "Für den Einzelnen ist es nur ein kleiner Betrag, aber alle Cents zusammen ergeben eine große Summe und können Kindern nachhaltig helfen." (from https://kinderheim-kleine-strolche.de/helfen-und-spenden-rest-cent)